# Scaling dynos... ! ▸ Couldn't find that process type (web). ERROR with DEPLOYMENT

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am attempting to deploy a project and have been met with a couple errors. I first checked my logs running: `heroku logs --tail`

which then ran error codes H14.

After researching I came to a solution of running

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

which then gives me the error of

```
Scaling dynos... !
 ▸    Couldn't find that process type (web).
```

My ProcFile looks like this

```
web: gunicorn takeitorleaveit.wsgi
release: python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is your `Procfile` named correctly? It cannot be `ProcFile` as you show in your question, but must be `Procfile` _exactly_. Is it in the root directory of your project? Do you have more than one? Are you sure you've deployed the correct branch?

Comment: It was not named correctly, and I had other bugs that I managed to fix as well thank you for the answer though!!